# Angular 2: Handling two parallel web service calls

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

I have two parallel web service calls. Sometimes, my first service call calling first and sometimes second one. My second service have a function, but that function requires my first service call data.

I tried do an if statement, like if firstData exist then call the other service. But didn't work

```
this.service.getFirstData(reqParams).then((data: any) => {
                        if (data.response) {
                            this.firstData = data.response;
                        }
                    }).catch(err => {
                            console.log(err);
                    });
this.service.getSecondData(data.user, this.itemselected).then((data: any) => {
                            if (data) {
                                this.listData = data.response.list;
                                this.calculateData();
                            }
                        }).catch((err: any) => {
                                console.log(err)
                        });
```

The service are asynchronous. How can I handle this weird behavior? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should call the second service on your first service callback , since first service is Asynchronous

```
   this.service.getFirstData(reqParams).then((data: any) => {
                            if (data.response) {
                                this.firstData = data.response;
//call your second service after the successful first service and then pass the data to the second service
                         this.service.getSecondData(data.user, 
                                     this.itemselected).then((data: any) => {
                                if (data) {
                                    this.listData = data.response.list;
                                    this.calculateData();
                                }
                            }).catch((err: any) => {
                                    console.log(err)
                            });
                          }
                        }).catch(err => {
                                console.log(err);
                        });
```

If you want to run any asynchronous call parallel using promise , if it's not dependent each other, you can try like below

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
       console.log(values);
      //call if any other service after succesful execution of promise
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: I tried this method, but there are some other parallel service calls are there too. So the getFirstData called first then other 3 or 4 service calls been fired and very last only getSecondData service call triggered. I need to fire these two immediately actually

Comment: @chewi please explain the complete flow of your all service and dependency with one another , else it's every  hard to answer

Comment: @chewi Updated my answer with little bit more information

Answer (score 0):

Luckily for us, there is an elegant way to execute multiple HTTP requests in Angular 2/4 and wait for all of them to complete. Let’s write a code sample for this scenario. All we need is two classes. A REST service where we encapsulate HTTP request methods and a component that needs to use the backend data.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {RestService} from "../rest.service";
@Component({
    selector: 'app-demo',
    templateUrl: './demo.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./demo.component.css']
})
export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {
    dataFromRequest1: any;  // data from url 1
    dataFromRequest2: any;  // data from url 2
    constructor(private restService: RestService) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.restService.getDataFromTwoResources().subscribe(responseList => {
            /*
            The response list is an array. In order to access data from each individual
            request, you need to use an index.
             */
            this.dataFromRequest1 = responseList[0];
            this.dataFromRequest2 = responseList[1];
        });
    }
}
```

Note: This technique can be used for gathering requests from multiple servers or from the same server. All you need to know are the URLs for the resources.